# HTACCESS redirect /admin to admin.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my nice urls working fine and heading to my `index.php` page, but I want to add one exception. I would like it if the user types in /admin that they get `admin.php` rather than `index.php`.

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

 # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

I tried adding this to the beginning of the file:

```
Redirect /admin admin.php
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick

Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php [L, NC]`?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Well I want to avoid rewrite rule because the admin area is using relative paths so I prefer to do a full redirect to not break any links to images etc. I just want them to have an easier link to remember, but doesn't need to look nice like the front-end

Comment: But `^admin$` means exactly `admin` and nothing else, it's not "things that start with admin" or anything. As for relative path issues, wouldn't the `<base>` tag help?